# Как сделать Share кнопки с текстом || JS

Tags: javascript, share, twitter

У меня есть страница на которой генерируется текст. Нужно сделать share кнопку на твитер. То есть когда я её нажму, меня должно перебрасывать на страницу с твитом с текстом который сгенерировался. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации всё описано https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-for-websites/tweet-button/overview

```
<a class="twitter-share-button" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Hello%20world">Tweet</a>
```